# How to work out the probability of 2 people having a different birthday

Tags: elementary-functions

I'm trying to reproduce the 'birthday problem' where you work out the probabilities of n people having the same / different birthday.

Theres a good example here: http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/games/puzzles/birthday.htm

I'm trying to reproduce this in excel and am wondering if anyone knows the various columns and column functions i'd need?

Comment: Select a random number from 1 to 365(or 366) using the `rand` function. Do that for ~`25` other rows. See if you have a collision(match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one column with the values of $n$ and one column with the function that calculates the probabilities. Say, that you have the $n$'s in column A, starting from cell A1. Then write in the cell B1 the following expression

---

"=(Fact(A1)*Combin(365;A1))/(365^A1)"

---

which calculates the probability $$p(n)=\frac{n!\dbinom{365}{n}}{365^n}$$ which is the probability that $n$ persons have different birthdays (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for an argumentation of the formula).